# Dynamic sizing fonts based on phone screen

Tags: ios, swift

I am interested in adjusting the size of the fonts I use dynamically based on the display device. The app is configured to only allow portrait-up display.

```
struct DisplayFonts {

    static let NavBarTitleFont = UIFont.init(name: "Montserrat-Bold", size: 20.0*fontSizeMultipler) //error 

    private var fontSizeMultipler: CGFloat {
        get {
            let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
            let screenWidth: CGFloat = screenSize.width
            let templateScreenWidth: CGFloat = 375.0

            return screenWidth / templateScreenWidth

        }
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments, I get the error `Cannot use instance member fontSizeMultipler`. I was wondering if there is another way to go about using my current `struct` so the font size could be updated by the screen size? Thaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just did a minor Mistake:

```
struct DisplayFonts {

    static let NavBarTitleFont = UIFont.init(name: "Montserrat-Bold", size: 20.0*fontSizeMultipler)

    private static var fontSizeMultipler: CGFloat {
        get {
            let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
            let screenWidth: CGFloat = screenSize.width
            let templateScreenWidth: CGFloat = 375.0

            return screenWidth / templateScreenWidth

        }
    }
}
```

See how i changed the the `var fontSizeMultipler` to static, now both Variables are on the same visibility level, now it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help and adding in the code segment!

Answer (score 1):

You should declare you fontSizeMultipler variable as static also:

```
private static var fontSizeMultipler: CGFloat
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is completely clear. You are using "fontSizeMultipler" to calculate a value for a property that is defined "static" so you need to define "fontSizeMultipler" as static too